# Display goes to sleep watching video

Tags: display, suspend, monitor

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 but there's a very annoying bug. When I'm watching videos (streaming or YouTube, not only in full-screen) the monitor goes to sleep. Some solution?
Thanks you!

Comment: nobody knows a solution? Caffeine does not work for now.

Comment: In particular, switching from Wayland to Xorg may fix this (see [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984555/22949)).