# Disable xscreensaver when watching Kodi video?

Tags: 17.10, kodi, xscreensaver

Is there any way of disabling xscreensaver when a video is being played back in Kodi (17.6). I'm running Ubuntu 17.10.

I've seen proposed workarounds for Flash or Youtube video playback, but nothing for Kodi
???

Comment: GNOME? Then see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969398/prevent-lock-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-17-10-while-watching-youtube-videos).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks as if the Gnome Tweak Tool and Caffeine offer some options for disabling the screensaver, but neither is smart enough to detect whether you are watching a video and disable the screensaver if you are (as Windows does, for example). Caffeine can spot whether you're running a full-screen app (e.g. Kodi), but not whether a video is playing. It seems that you can set rules for when to disable the screensaver, but they're not smart enough to work out when you're actually watching a video.

Answer (score 1):

[**kodi-prevent-xscreensaver**](https://github.com/graysky2/kodi-prevent-xscreensaver) 
keeps XScreenSaver from coming on when Kodi is active. This bash script is infinitely more lightweight than some alternatives such as caffeine.

```
git clone https://github.com/graysky2/kodi-prevent-xscreensaver 
sudo make  
sudo make install 

kodi-prevent-xscreensaver
```

and add it to `~/.config/autostart` to add it to start-up application list
but this prevents it any time Kodi is running, not only when it is at full screen.

Comment: `sudo` should be generally not needed when calling `make` without parameters.