# Automatic suspend - "Computer will suspend very soon because of inactivity" - how can I disable this?

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, aptitude

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on VM.

In the guest I opened GNOME terminal, launched Aptitude with `sudo aptitude`, then switched to the host machine to do some tasks.
When I returned to the Ubuntu guest it was showing this notification on lock screen:

> **Power**
>    1 new notification

[image: popup]

and after unlocking:

> Automatic suspend
>   Computer will suspend very soon because of inactivity.

[image: popup]

Just after unlocking Aptitude says that it can't download packages because the system is offline.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969398/how-to-prevent-the-screen-lock-while-watching-video-netflix-youtube-amazon-pr)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to disable automatic suspend:

1. Open *GNOME Control Center*, go to *Power* tab (or simply `gnome-control-center power`)
2. In *Suspend & Power Button* set *Automatic suspend*, to *Off* when *Plugged In*.

[image: <code>gnome-control-center power</code>]

This will change settings from

```
$ dconf dump / | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=900
sleep-inactive-ac-type='suspend' # <
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=900

$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend' # <
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

to

```
$ dconf dump / | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=900
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing' # <
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=900

$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "suspend\|sleep"
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing' # <
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

Comment: I don't use a GNONE desktop, so actually had to run `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center power` but otherwise great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: What if this setting is missing from my GNOME, but I still get such notifications?

Comment: @Suncatcher Which version do you have? I see this option in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I have 18.04 too. My Gnome is 3.28.1 and Power settings look [like this](https://imgur.com/wlpBZFf). I run Ubuntu on Hyper-V VM, btw.

Comment: I'm running VirtualBox guest. I'm sorry, but I can reproduce this on Hyper-V (I do not have any). You can try to disable it from terminal with `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'` and `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'`.

Comment: Awesome! manual `gsettings` worked

Comment: in 22.04 the panel looks completely different. 3 power options for the laptop. nothing about suspend.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary:**

Setting->Power : Suspend: "off"

Or open a terminal, and execute the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

**Detailed:**

Use the setting dialog "Power" and set the automatic suspension to "OFF".
Sometimes the setting is not available in the setting-dialog; it is simply missing.
(e.g. Only the screen-timeout is shown.)

Please use a terminal instead then.

Check the current setting with the command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

it should reply:

```
'suspend'
```

Please check if the key is writable:

```
gsettings writable org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

it should reply:

```
true
```

Check the range:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

it should reply:

```
enum
'blank'
'suspend'
'shutdown'
'hibernate'
'interactive'
'nothing'
'logout'
```

And set the value (with single, double or no quote on "nothing") to your choice:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

Check afterwards, if the setting has changed:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

it should show your changes:

```
'nothing'
```

Hint: Please avoid to use sudo or a root shell, this will prohibit the access to the local settings.

Comment: The hint to avoid being in a root shell helped a lot! I got a `dconf` / `dbus-launch` error otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add that given the myriad versions of the GUI control centre that appear to be floating around (mine looks nothing like the one upthread) I found the easiest way to make this change was:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type "nothing"
```