# Exploring gnome settings of a non-running system disk

Tags: gnome, 22.04, power-management, dconf, gsettings

I've read, e.g. here: [How to save GNOME settings in a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984205/how-to-save-gnome-settings-in-a-file) that gnome settings are stored in a binary database, therefore I guess I won't be able to look at those binary files manually (I don't even know where they are on a system disk).

I have a system hard drive A, holding an Ubuntu 22.04 installation, this is the bootable primary drive.
I have a system hard drive B, which is also holding an Ubuntu 22.04 installation.

System disk B is not bootable and is plugged as a secondary drive, mounted in `/mnt/diskB` as seen from Ubuntu on drive A.

I wish I could explore the gnome settings of drive **B** from drive **A**, especially those about [hibernation/suspend/sleep](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014968/571173).

Is this possible?

Comment: Try this: assuming backup is `/backup/home/user` do `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/backup/home/user/.config dconf dump /`