# Did Xubuntu 22.04 remove the ability for programs to inhibit power management?

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, 22.04, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

In Xubuntu 20.04, having a video playing would put a note on my power manager saying that a particular program is inhibiting power management. I can't remember if they needed to be in full screen or not. Regardless, this would mean that my machine wouldn't lock/sleep while a video was playing. In 22.04, I am not seeing this behavior. I've tested this with both VLC and (Snap) Firefox, but I'm neither seeing a note nor having locks prevented.

Comment: looks like it's a Wayland thing, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/969398/how-to-prevent-the-screen-lock-while-watching-video-netflix-youtube-amazon-pr . Try switching back to xorg and see if that changes anything.

Comment: also check the screensaver settings, the option might be there

Comment: @Esther I don't believe that I'm on Wayland. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` prints `x11`.

Comment: @Esther My screensaver is entirely disabled. It can't be that.

Comment: Just a comment. I don't let computer put itself to sleep, I invoke a process for it to go to sleep.

Comment: I am on vanilla Ubuntu 22.04 and I see the same issue. Whenever I watch a movie through `mplayer` I need to move my mouse every 10 minutes to prevent the screens to turn off. Did you get anywhere with this ?

Comment: @pieroxy I don't really know about Ubuntu. Xubuntu's different.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not. Both Steam and Microsoft Teams inhibit power management when making calls. It is as if the issue is specifically with video playing.